# JavaScript beginner, if a variable does not match to do something

Tags: javascript

Basically what I'm trying to do is write a greasemonkey script so that if a link on a page is not a link I have on an ignore list to just open the link, if it is on the list then reload the page after 5 seconds here is what I tried so far

```
var url1 =  $("span.capsulelink a:eq(0) ").attr("href");
var ignoreList = ["example1.com","example2.com"]
if (url1 !== ignoreList) {
    window.open(url1);
} else {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();  
    },5000);
}
```

I know it's the  (`url1 !== ignoreList`) part I am having trouble with, I just can not seem to find the right expression for that. Like I do not know how to say if `url1` is not on the `ignoreList` {do something}.

Comment: First lesson: Java **IS NOT** JavaScript

Comment: Second: you're comparing a string (`url1`) with an array (`ignoreList`) directly, when you should compare the string with the contents of the array.

Comment: Opps sorry about that, Thanks for editing the post to reflex that.

Comment: This seems like basic JS and a tiny bit of jQuery. Are the greasemonkey and tampermonkey tags necessary?

Comment: that was what i was writng the script to use in, I did not know that that didnt matter. sorry ill remover them

Comment: it's important to note that all the answers so far rely on `url1` matching (or not matching depending on how you want to look at it) one of the entries in `ignoreList` **exactly** - i.e. same case, exactly the same string - in the example code, it's unlikely that the url in the href would be `example1.com` or `example2.com` as that suggests an external link (by the name) - it's more likely that those links would be `http://example1.com/` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, because the answer really isn't intuitive.

When you're starting to learn `javascript`, some of the syntax patterns begin to look familiar.

But the javascript equivalent of PHP's

```
if (!in_array([ARRAY]));
```

simply isn't obvious at all - this is one syntax you just need to know.

Here is the `javascript` you're looking for:

```
if (ignoreList.indexOf(url1) !== -1) {

[RELOAD PAGE CODE HERE]

}

else {

[OPEN THE LINK CODE HERE]

}
```

Here's why it works:

`ignoreList.indexOf([VALUE])` looks through the `ignoreList` array and searches through the array's items.

If one of those items *is* `[VALUE]`, it returns the index of that item.

Importantly, if *none* of the items are `[VALUE]` it returns `-1`.

So, in order to establish that *at least one* of the items *is* `[VALUE]`, you have to verify that the returned index definitely *isn't* `-1`.

Consequently the condition you need to check for is:

```
if (ignoreList.indexOf(url1) !== -1)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, Like i said Im really new with this stuff and trying to learn on my own. This is what I ended up with

Comment: if (ignoreList.indexOf(url1) === -1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();  
},5000);
}
else {
    window.open(url1);
}

Answer (score 2):

`ignoreList.indexOf(url1) !== -1`

This is another way of saying "is `url` contained in the `ignoreList` array?"

This is because the `indexOf()` method of `Array` returns the index of the element you're looking for, or `-1` if the element doesn't exist.

To negate this, which is what you want to do, you write:

`ignoreList.indexOf(url1) === -1`

(i.e. is `url1` *not* in `ignoreList`?)

Comment: or `!~ignoreList.indexOf(url1)`

Comment: That's technically correct, but bitwise operations are not intuitive for beginners.